# Hide Reach UI Tooltip upon Scroll

Tags: reactjs, tooltip

I'm using ReactJS and Tooltip from Reach UI (https://reach.tech/tooltip/). I would like to hide the tooltip when the user scrolls up or down the webpage. Can I do this organically within ReachUI, i.e. I don't want an answer that involves listening for scrolling events? If so, how?